# Vagrant provisioning fails: Cookbook vagrant not found

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

When executing `vagrant reload --provision` it fails during executing `chef_solo`. This happend all of a sudden with two different boxes on multiple machines running on OSX.
Google didn't show up anything and there seems no `vagrant-berkshelf` plugin being installed.

Output in the console while provisioning:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
==> default: Detected Chef (latest) is already installed Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> default: Running chef-solo...
==> default: [2015-03-04T08:28:55+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> default: [2015-03-04T08:28:55+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.6.0 ***
==> default: [2015-03-04T08:28:58+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[vagrant]"] from JSON
==> default: [2015-03-04T08:28:58+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[vagrant]]
==> default: [2015-03-04T08:28:58+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [vagrant]
==> default: [2015-03-04T08:28:58+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for example.lo
==> default: [2015-03-04T08:28:58+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> default: [2015-03-04T08:28:58+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
==> default: [2015-03-04T08:28:58+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: [2015-03-04T08:28:58+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: [2015-03-04T08:28:58+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2015-03-04T08:28:58+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Content of inside the box `/var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out`:

```
Generated at 2015-03-04 08:28:58 +0000
Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook vagrant not found. If you're loading vagrant from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/cookbook/cookbook_collection.rb:38:in `block in initialize'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-6.18.0/lib/ohai/mash.rb:77:in `yield'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-6.18.0/lib/ohai/mash.rb:77:in `default'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-6.18.0/lib/ohai/mash.rb:77:in `default'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:265:in `[]'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:265:in `each_cookbook_dep'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:243:in `add_cookbook_with_deps'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:87:in `block in cookbook_order'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:85:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:85:in `cookbook_order'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:97:in `compile_libraries'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:70:in `compile'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/run_context.rb:86:in `load'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:249:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:492:in `do_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:199:in `block in run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:193:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:193:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/application.rb:183:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:239:in `block in run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:231:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:231:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/application.rb:66:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is a bug with Vagrant 1.7.2, downgrading to 1.6.5 seems to solve the problem on all affected machines.